# auto increment for the table with 1000 of records in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to reset auto increment for the table with 1000 of records in mysql. I want it to start counting from 1 again.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you show what you have tried so far, please, what errors you see and what part of the documentation is confusing or unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to 1 with this command:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

More info in the mysql manuals, here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: That won't work unless you first removed all rows with id >= 1.  Do _not_ assume properties of auto_increment; you _will_ be bitten in mysterious ways.